# Setting up and tearing down repeatedly in boost.test?

Tags: c++, testing, boost

Here is the code, adapted from http://www.alittlemadness.com/2009/03/31/c-unit-testing-with-boosttest/

```
// t.cpp
#define BOOST_TEST_DYN_LINK
#define BOOST_TEST_MODULE Hello
#include <boost/test/included/unit_test.hpp>

double add(double i, double j)
{
    return i + j;
}

int add(int i, int j)
{
    return i + j;
}


struct Massive {
    int a;
    int b;
    int c;
    double a1;
    double b1;
    double c1;

    Massive() : a(1), b(2), c(3), a1(1.1), b1(2.2), c1(3.3) {
        BOOST_TEST_MESSAGE("set up massive fixture...");
    }
    ~Massive() {
        BOOST_TEST_MESSAGE("tear down massive fixture...");
    }
};

BOOST_FIXTURE_TEST_SUITE(Adding, Massive)
BOOST_AUTO_TEST_CASE(universeInOrder)
{
    BOOST_CHECK(add(2, 2) == 4);
}
BOOST_AUTO_TEST_CASE(addingInt) {
    BOOST_CHECK_EQUAL(add(a, b), c);
}
BOOST_AUTO_TEST_CASE(addingDouble) {
    BOOST_CHECK(add(a1, b1) - c1 < .0000001);
}
BOOST_AUTO_TEST_SUITE_END()
```

It compiles and runs ok:

```
g++ -o test -lboost_unit_test_framework t.cpp
./test --log_level=test_suite

Running 3 test cases...
Entering test suite "Hello"
Entering test suite "Adding"
Entering test case "universeInOrder"
set up massive fixture...
tear down massive fixture...
Leaving test case "universeInOrder"
Entering test case "addingInt"
set up massive fixture...
tear down massive fixture...
Leaving test case "addingInt"
Entering test case "addingDouble"
set up massive fixture...
tear down massive fixture...
Leaving test case "addingDouble"
Leaving test suite "Adding"
Leaving test suite "Hello"


*** No errors detected
```

**The problem is it seems to be setting up the fixture repeatedly for each test case, which is a waste of time.**

Another small confusion is why this line

```
BOOST_FIXTURE_TEST_SUITE(Adding, Massive)
```

is closed with

```
BOOST_AUTO_TEST_SUITE_END()
```

instead of

```
BOOST_FIXTURE_TEST_SUITE_END()
```

??

Comment: It seems you've been trying lots of testing frameworks this day ;)

Comment: Yes. So far I am happier with boost.test than with googletest. :D

Comment: Really? Oh well, it's a matter of personal taste I'd suppose. Boost.Test didn't work out for me because of the degradation in compilation performance.

Comment: I see. Maybe hand written code is better than any testing framework.

Comment: It might be for small projects, but what about testing code that can break in the most horrible way possible (e.g. by abruptly terminating the process)? Are you gonna handle that? GTest does it out of the box.

Answer (score 0):

This is by design.  To keep tests independent of each other you want a [fresh fixture](http://xunitpatterns.com/Fresh%20Fixture.html) for each test case.  Otherwise, the tests are sharing data which leads to a [fragile test](http://xunitpatterns.com/Fragile%20Test.html).  Your example isn't particularly representative of real-world unit testing with Boost.Test IMO.  I show realistic examples of how to use fixtures in my [documentation rewrite](http://user.xmission.com/~legalize/boost.test/libs/test/doc/html/index.html) and in [part 5](http://legalizeadulthood.wordpress.com/2009/07/05/c-unit-tests-with-boost-test-part-5/) set of tutorials on Test-Driven Development in C++ with Boost.Test I wrote in 2009.